# System.LoadLibrary during runtime or controlled by user

Tags: java, android-ndk, java-native-interface, jna

Is it possible to load a native library in response to user interaction by means of UI event? Eg, button click etc calls System.LoadLibrary(file_chosen_dynamically) or conditional loading (in the case of a CLI) Perhaps a good example would be like a file picker to select the dll/so file

From what I understand, this is done when the class instantiates. Can I just call System.LoadLibrary as desired or do I need to use class loader?

Is this the same with all platforms (Android/Desktop)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to load a native library in response to user interaction by means of UI event?

Technically, yes.

> From what I understand, this is done when the class instantiates.

That is the *normal* way to do it.  You normally put the `loadLibrary` call into a `static` block so that it is executed when the class initializes.

> Can I just call System.LoadLibrary as desired or do I need to use class loader?

1. Yes (technically)
2. No.  A class loader isn't / doesn't need to be involved.

I say "technically", because there is a practical problem with calling `loadLibrary` somewhere other than in a `static` initializer block.

The primary effect of calling `loadLibrary` is that `native` methods declarations will be "bound" to the corresponding native code implementations.  If you call `loadLibrary` at class initialization time, then you are pretty much guaranteed that the binding has happened before the native methods can be called. But, if you call `loadLibrary` at another time (after class initialization), there is a risk that some code will call a native method before it has been bound to its implementation.  That will trigger an `Error` ... and it is pretty much game over.

So ... rather than interactively selecting a DLL, I think you are better off having a one-to-one relationship between DLLs and Java classes, and interactively selecting a class to be loaded using `Class.forName`.

---

> Is this the same with all platforms (Android/Desktop)

I believe so ...

Comment: Another benefit of the static loading pattern is that it matches the "load once" nature of JNA libraries.  Loading using another pattern, one might be tempted to `dispose()` of the library, and that introduces concerns with timing, thread safety, etc.